# Require statement as an argument of a function

Tags: php

I've seen this code:

```
App::bind('config', require 'config.php');
```

I am still making the first steps into PHP and I cannot understand why a statement can be added as an argument in a method's call.

On the other hand I would understand `require` as a function in the same situation:

```
App::bind('config', require ('config.php'));
```

Is Passing `required` as a statement OK? If yes, how is it possible? Using `require` as a **statement** or a **function** is completely interchangeable?

Comment: It's ugly code, but `require` actually returns a value, and it's that value which is being passed as the argument to `App::bind()`

Comment: The point is that you don't "pass a statement" as a parameter, you pass its _result_.

Comment: Thank you both:) I think I understand but if I used a raw if statement inside a method's call wouldn't be allowed for sure, even if the if statement returned a value, or is it allowed?

Comment: @viery365 The `if` statement doesn't return a value. But the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) does.

Comment: @Progman OK, thank you! So, in that case anything that returns a value (even a ternary operator) can be used. Now I got it!